# jQuery slideToggle ul when clicking on parent li

Tags: jquery, css, slidetoggle

1.) If I click on the image, all of the "Topics" (ul) should close and change their class. I could manage to change the class, but they won't close.

I thought this:

```
$("#nav ul li.open").slideToggle('fast');
```

would work in this function:

```
$("#home").click(function (e) {
    // Prevent the default action of the event
    e.preventDefault();
    var linkHref = this.id + '.html';
    $("#content").load(linkHref);
    $("#nav a.active").toggleClass('inactive active');
    $("#nav ul li.open").slideToggle('fast');          //slideToggle here
    $("#nav li.open").toggleClass('closed open');
});
```

but it's not working.

2.) If I open Topic 1 and Subtopic 2 and then click on Topic 2, Topic 1 will be closed. But when I click on Topic 1 again, Subtopic 2 is still open. So the nested ul won't be closed.

3.) I want to color the Topic and Subtopic Text when a link is active (has the class .active).

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/XuVnN/)

Answer (score 0):

What you're missing is to hide the children too, so you have to replace `$("#nav ul li.open").slideToggle('fast');`  with `$("#nav li ul").css('display',"none");`. Tested in your fiddle and it works